# Implementar token CSRF mas sem afetar a navegação

Tags: php, csrf

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web escrita em PHP7. Neste aplicação, desenvolvi  um módulo no qual gera no token CSRF automaticamente quando o usuário "entrar" em qualquer página da aplicação. Este é a parte útil do código para a pergunta:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['csrftoken']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET')
{
    SessionController::CriarCSRFToken(); 
}


// Na classe SessionController...
public static function CriarCSRFToken()
{
    $_SESSION['csrftoken'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}
```

A minha intensão é sempre realizar uma verificação de token em toda requisição do tipo POST. O código útil para a pergunta é esse:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    SessionController::VerificarCSRFToken();
}

//Na classe SessionController...
public static function VerificarCSRFToken()
{
    if (!isset($_POST['csrftoken']) || !hash_equals($_SESSION['csrftoken'], $_POST['csrftoken']))
    {

        //Basicamente envia a mensagem e para a execução da requisição.
        JSONResponder::ResponderFalha("Você não tem permição para acessar essa funcionalidade", true, true);
    }
}
```

Está funcionando bem, porém, isto gera um problema de usabilidade para a aplicação. Ações como utilizar várias abas do navegador ou só verificar código fonte da página gera atualização no csrftoken da sessão. Por exemplo, estou na aba1 com o token "abc", mas então abro uma nova aba aba2, o módulo atualiza o token para "bcd". Ai está o problema. Se eu tentar fazer uma requisição POST na aba1, o módulo vai "negar" a requisição. Isto acontece porque na aba1 o token ainda é "abc" porém quando abri a aba2 o token ficou "bcd".

Então, como posso resolver este problema? Espero que tenha eu deixado a minha pergunta clara.

Comment: Eu nunca trabalhei com **SESSION**, nesse caso eu usaria **COOKIES**, mas não sei se isso pode abrir brecha de segurança no `CSRF`. Eu não vou colocar uma resposta de como fazer agora por que estou sem tempo pra testar se realmente funcionaria.

Comment: Adicionar um `input` do tipo *hidden* no formulário, resolve isso. Por que ter um hash para CSRF em "qualquer página"?

Comment: Adicionar um input do tipo hidden é uma das coisas que estou fazendo. Porém se o usuário está na aba1 o valor do input var ser por exemplo "abc", mas se o usuário abrir outra aba aba2 no navegador, o módulo vai atualizar o valor do token para por exemplo "bcd". Se o usuário querer então, realizar um submit no formulário na aba1, este formulário do input hidden vai estar com o valor desatualizado.